# БЭМ и состояния блока

Tags: javascript, html, css, бэм

Каким образом, в соответствии с БЭМ, реализовать кнопку имеющую два состояния: нажата и не нажата? Использовать псевдо-классы или создать модификаторы? Но ведь если создавать модификаторы управлять состояниями придется через JavaScript, а это немного убого.

Comment: Зачем громоздить лишний код, если можно сделать проще? Не пытайтесь строго следовать бэм и делать это идеально, из этого мало что получится.

Comment: Зачем вы все на БЭМ равняетесь?))) это ахтунг полный

Comment: @E_K т.е. использовать псевдо-классы, где это возможно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, лучше использовать всё-таки классы, по нескольким причинам:

1. Возможность эмулировать состояния блоков, через JS (с `hover` или `active` такое не пройдет (`click()` - это не выход)).
2. Даже если использовать псевдо-классы, часть (большую) компонентов придется написать на JS